# Can my user access the content of $_SESSION by clicking a button short of Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I have an array of arrays in `$_SESSION`. I want to print the first sub-array in an HTML table and then populate the table with the next element each time the user clicks on a button. I know how to do that using Ajax. That seems like overkill (after all I don't need to retrieve more data from my db). Is there a different way for my user to access `$_SESSION` (e.g., with Javascript alone)?

Comment: The data in $_SESSION is (normally) stored *on* the server. Thus the client *only* gets what the server returns (such as the response to an HTTP/XHR request).

Comment: why would "making the browser talk to your server, to get data from the server" be overkill? You users are in their browser, your PHP is running on the server, there is nothing other than "make the browser ask the server" that is going to get that data from php to the webpage.

Comment: So, the answer is no, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to keep going back to the server for `$_SESSION`, and there is no data that is actually changing in `$_SESSION`, then why not just serve all the data that the client will need when the page loads? So just populate the whole table (unless this results in a performance problem, but that's usually not the case) and show more and more of the table with every click using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var sessionContent = [];
<?php foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val){ ?>
    sessionContent.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

Now the session data is available to you to use in the browser.

Caution: Make sure that you want to send everything in the SESSION variable to the browser.